# Set Namespace prefix in XML using Google Apps Script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to create the following structure in a XML file using Google Apps Script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/">
  <fields>
    <field name="TestingXML">
      <value>Some Testing Value</value> 
    </field>
    <field name="Address_es_:prefill">
      <value>Client Address</value>
    </field>
    <field name="Address1_es_:prefill">
      <value>Project Address</value>
    </field>
  </fields>
</xfdf>
```

The problem comes when trying to set the Namespace prefix:

> xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/"

Here is my code so far:

```
  var contractInfo = [
    ["Customer Name_es_:prefill","ownerFullName"],
    ["Address_es_:prefill", "clientAddress"],
    ["Address_Project_es_:prefill", "projectAddress"]
  ];

function CreateXML(contractInfo){
  //Define Namespace
  var nsh = XmlService.getNamespace('http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/');

 //Create the root element and set the namespace
  var root = XmlService.createElement('xfdf', nsh);
  
  //Create the next section
  var fields = XmlService.createElement('fields');
  root.addContent(fields); //attach this section to the root
  
  //Loop and create the rest of sections based on an 2D array object.
  for(var m = 0; m < contractInfo.length; m++){

    var child1 = XmlService.createElement('field')
    .setAttribute('name', contractInfo[m][0]);
    
    var chiled2 = XmlService.createElement('value').setText(contractInfo[m][1]);
    child1.addContent(chiled2);
    fields.addContent(child1);
  }
  
  var document = XmlService.createDocument(root);
  //var xml = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
  Logger.log(document);
}
```

However, when running this code I'm getting to following error in the `Logger.log`

```
[Document:  No DOCTYPE declaration, Root is [Element: <xfdf [Namespace: http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/]/>]]
```

Ideally the output XML would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/">
  <fields>
    <field name="TestingXML">
      <value>Some Testing Value</value> 
    </field>
    <field name="Address_es_:prefill">
      <value>Client Address</value>
    </field>
    <field name="Address1_es_:prefill">
      <value>Project Address</value>
    </field>
  </fields>
</xfdf>
```

I believe I'm missing this section at the begining:

> xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"

However, this was being created by itself. How can I get around this No DOCTYPE declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create the following xml data using Google Apps Script.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/">
    <fields>
      <field name="TestingXML">
        <value>Some Testing Value</value>
      </field>
      <field name="Address_es_:prefill">
        <value>Client Address</value>
      </field>
      <field name="Address1_es_:prefill">
        <value>Project Address</value>
      </field>
    </fields>
  </xfdf>
  ```

For this, how about this modification? In your script, in order to retrieve the result xml data, please use `XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document)`. And also, there are several modification points in your script for achieving above sample value. So also, I modified them.

#### Modified script:

```
function CreateXML(contractInfo){

  // This is a sample value. Please modify this for your actual situation.
  var contractInfo = [
    ["TestingXML","Some Testing Value"],
    ["Address_es_:prefill", "Client Address"],
    ["Address1_es_:prefill", "Project Address"]
  ];

  var nsh = XmlService.getNamespace('http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/');
  var root = XmlService.createElement('xfdf', nsh);
  var fields = XmlService.createElement('fields', nsh);  // Modified
  for(var m = 0; m < contractInfo.length; m++){
    var child1 = XmlService.createElement('field', nsh).setAttribute('name', contractInfo[m][0]);  // Modified
    var chiled2 = XmlService.createElement('value', nsh).setText(contractInfo[m][1]);  // Modified
    child1.addContent(chiled2);
    fields.addContent(child1);
  }
  root.addContent(fields);  // Added
  var document = XmlService.createDocument(root);
  var res = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);  // Added
  console.log(res);
}
```

- Your sample output value is different from the value of `contractInfo` in your script. So I used the following `contractInfo` as the sample value.

  ```
  var contractInfo = [
    ["TestingXML","Some Testing Value"],
    ["Address_es_:prefill", "Client Address"],
    ["Address1_es_:prefill", "Project Address"]
  ];
  ```
- When above script is run, the sample output values as shown above section can be obtained.

#### References:

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)
- [getPrettyFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#getprettyformat)
- [format(document)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/format#format(Document))

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, it works great. Is it OK to say that everytime we create a Namespace for the root, we need to pass this namespace to the rest of elements? Thanks again

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, I think that it's yes. But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So I'm not sure whether this can be used for your all situation. I apologize for this.